# D3.js create triangle totally inside the svg container

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have to create 30 triangle in random position; for the shape I am using the d3.symbolTriangle and I can set the dimension of it through attr("d", triangle.size(dim), that should be the area of the triangle.
The problem is that some triangle are not totally inside the svg container, that has some borders, and some parts of these triangles are outside (see in the picture).
How can I force these inside the container, like with a margine of x pixel?
This is my code:

```
 var width = window.innerWidth;
 var height = window.innerHeight;
 var triangle = d3.symbol()
    .type(d3.symbolTriangle);

 function drawTriangles(number) {
  for(var i=0;i<number;i++){
    var dim = Math.random()*300;
    console.log("Path: "+i+", dim: "+dim);
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", triangle.size(dim))
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + Math.random()*width + "," + Math.random()*height + ")"; })
        .attr("fill", "rgb("+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+","+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+","+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+")")
        .attr("opacity", 2)
        .attr("class", "path"+i);
    }
}
```

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jjr3kqao/

You can see the blue triangle that is not inside the container:
[image: Effect]

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for better help?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jjr3kqao/

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use the element bounding box size when you set it's translate value.

It's strange, but for triangles to fully be inside svg, using bbox height does not work. Shapes width are a couple of pixels larger than their heights and using that value in computations works.

```js
var width = 250;
var height = 250;
var number = 30;
var borderSize = 1;
var body = d3.select("body");
var triangle = d3.symbol()
  .type(d3.symbolTriangle);

var svg = body.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("border", "1px solid black");


function drawTriangles(number) {
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    var dim = Math.random() * 300;
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", triangle.size(dim))
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
        var boundingBox = this.getBBox();
        var elementWidth = Math.ceil(boundingBox.width);
        var randomXOffset = Math.random() * (width - elementWidth - 2 * borderSize) + elementWidth/2 + borderSize;
        var randomYOffset = Math.random() * (height - elementWidth - 2 * borderSize) + elementWidth/2 + borderSize;
        return "translate(" + randomXOffset + "," + randomYOffset + ")";
      })
      .attr("fill", "rgb(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + "," + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + "," + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + ")")
      .attr("opacity", 2)
      .attr("class", "path" + i);
  }
}

drawTriangles(number);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I see that also with this code I have the same problem (see the image). How can I force more the bound? If I put for example this.getBBox()+10 all the triangles are near the (0,0) point, in the top left corner. http://imgur.com/2OrmVeA

Comment: @MaVeRicK_91 Does error occur when you run my code snippet? You can run it multiple times to assure problem is gone. If the problem still exists, drop me a fiddle showing it.

Comment: Yes, the image in the comment is from your code; maybe it is for the border that I have put?

Comment: @MaVeRicK_91 Using shapes width for both height and width offset seems to work. Check it out.

Comment: Yes, it seems working well. If it not, I will write here. Thanks you man

Answer (score 1):

If you set the desired margin:

```
var margin = 20;
```

You can avoid the triangles having their *center* positioned within that margin:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) 
    { return "translate(" + (margin + Math.random()*(width - margin)) 
    + "," + (margin + Math.random()*(height - margin)) + ")"; 
})
```

Have in mind that this doesn't take in consideration the fact that the triangles have different sizes: it sets the same margin for everyone.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7qkqtwmu/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't work. I see the size method of d3.symbolTriangle() and it consider to drawing it the center of the triangle, so if half side or half height of the triangle is bigger than margin, the triangle will be out.

Comment: That's precisely what I said in my answer! Just set the margin for more than half the maximum size of the symbol, out use getBBox, as in the other answer.

Comment: Excuse I didn't understand, my english is a shit. So the max dimension of the triangle is 300 (dim = Math.random()*300): I put margin = 310 and all the triangles are not displayed in the container.

Comment: No, way less than that! A triangle with a size of 300 needs a margin of less than 20 pixels, just as in my code above. Listen, just use Saeed's answer, it's better for you.

Comment: Ok, I will write to him. Thank you for the time.